# for будто не виден, просто его пропускает

Tags: c#

нужно посчитать последовательность, но то, что  в for, он просто пропускает, и выдает начальное значение double result

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace codewars23
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 9;
        Console.WriteLine(seriesSum(n));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


public static string seriesSum (int n) 
{
float result = 1;
int p = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  result = result + 1/(p + 3);
  p = p + 3;
  //string a = result.ToString("0.00");
}
 string a = result.ToString("0.00");
//string a = result;
//a = String.Format("{0:0.00}",a);//2 цифры после точки в том числе и 0
return a;
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком посмотрите.

Comment: 1,00 //Он выводит

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В выражении `1/(p + 3)` результат преобразуется к int. Достаточно указать тип `float` для `1`:

```
result = result + 1f / (p + 3);
```

или изменить тип у переменной `p`:

```
float p = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`1/(p + 3)` всегда равно нулю - целочисленное деление. Исправление `1.0f/(Convert.ToSingle(p) + 3.0f)`